# python matplotlib how make fixed width Bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I am using this code to generate a Bar chart from a dynamic source the problem that i have is that when i have less then 10 Bars the width of the bars change and it is no the same layout here is the code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
from  Processesing import dataProcess

def chartmak (dic) :
    z = 0

    D={}
    D=dic
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    n = len(D)
    ax.barh(range(n), D.values(), align='center', fc='#80d0f1', ec='w')
    ax.set_yticks(range(n))

    #this need more work to put the GB or the TB
    ax.set_yticklabels(['{:3d} GB'.format(e) for e in D.values()], color='gray')
    ax.tick_params(pad=10)
    for i, (label, val) in enumerate(D.items()):
        z+=1
        ax.annotate(label.title(), xy=(10, i), fontsize=12, va='center')
    for spine in ('top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'):
        ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks([])
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(length=0)

    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    plt.savefig("test.png")
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just pad your dictionary entries if there are less than 10 as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def chartmak(dic):
    entries = list(dic.items())

    if len(entries) < 10:
        entries.extend([('', 0)] * (10 - len(entries)))

    values = [v for l, v in entries]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    n = len(entries)
    ax.barh(range(n), values, align='center', fc='#80d0f1', ec='w')
    ax.set_yticks(range(n))

    #this need more work to put the GB or the TB
    ax.set_yticklabels(['' if e == 0 else '{:3d} GB'.format(e) for e in values], color='gray')
    ax.tick_params(pad=10)

    for i, (label, val) in enumerate(entries):
        ax.annotate(label.title(), xy=(10, i), fontsize=12, va='center')

    for spine in ('top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'):
        ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)

    ax.xaxis.set_ticks([])
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(length=0)

    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    plt.show()


chartmak({'1': 10, '2':20, '3':30})
chartmak({'1': 10, '2':20, '3':30, '4':40, '5':80, '6':120, '7':100, '8':50, '9':30, '10':40})
```

This would show the following output:

[image: v1]

[image: v2]

Comment: Hello When i atry your code i have the following error :

Comment: entries.extend([('', 0)] * (10 - len(entries)))
AttributeError: 'dict_items' object has no attribute 'extend'

Comment: What version of Python are you using? This was tested in Python 2.7.9

Comment: For Python 3.5, the following line needs to be changed `entries = list(dic.items())`

Comment: Sorry to bother you agian but change to what ? Because python 3.5 supports list()

Comment: I have already made the change to the example, previously there was no `list()`, which would have caused your error when used in 3.5 (but not in Python 2.7)

Comment: Ah sorry i am using the mobile app and i didnt noticed sorry agian i will try tomorrow and give you an update